# Is the marketing control panel available in Sitecore 9.1 XM?

Tags: personalization, marketing-control-panel

I am doing some investigation into in-session personalisation, no historical data being stored with xDb. I have everything working with XP but as I do not require any of the additional functionality it provides I was wondering if it could be done under an XM licence.

Multiple sources including the [Sitecore website](https://www.sitecore.com/en-gb/products/sitecore-experience-platform/wcm) state that in-session personalisation is possible but I am unable to find the marketing control panel to setup any of the profile keys.

If there a flag I need to switch in the config or some other process that needs to be followed.

Answer (score 1):

The Marketing control panel and some other parts of the puzzle have been removed from the XM version for performance reasons. I am led to believe you are able to run an XP version with xDb disabled under an XM licence. I would recommend checking with Sitecore for clarification on this though.